# What do you call the method DI uses to populate a model?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Implementations of IHost like the generic host do dependency injection. You populate a services collection with helper methods like this

```
  IConfigurationSection section;
  section = config.GetSection("SectionName");
  services.Configure<SectionModel>(section);
```

Inside the `Configure` helper method some magic creates an instance of SectionModel and populates it from the `IConfigurationSection` object.

What is that called? I need to do it in the absence of the DI and while I'm sure rummaging through Microsoft source code would probably yield answers I could rummage a lot faster armed with the name of the method that does it.

More than likely they just use reflection, but I'd prefer not to implement this myself and have potentially divergent behaviour.

Comment: "What is that called?" Model binding? Deserialization? It has little to do with DI. DI is about injecting dependencies, but this is about loading data.

Comment: @Steven what it has to do with DI is simply that DI does it and I wanted to know what DI calls so that I can have exactly the same behaviour in the absence of DI. DI has _everything_ to do with it, since it is the context for assessment of compatibility.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. When you mention "DI" in your question, you are referring to "the .NET Core configuration system". This configuration system includes Dependency Injection functionality. And it is this configuration system that loads configuration files and model binds them to POCO classes. I view the configuration system and the DI Container as two different things. In fact, I view a DI Container (i.e. the library) and DI (i.e. the set of principles, patterns, and practices) as two separate things. That might have caused our misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) this is called `Bind` and is surfaced on `IConfigurationSection`.

First you create the config section and model objects, then you call `Bind` like so

```cs
var sectionModel = new SectionModel();
config.GetSection("SectionName").Bind(sectionModel);
```

@Nkosi comments

> The same can be done using
>
> `var sectionModel = config.GetSection("SectionName").Get<SectionModel>();`

This is a more elegant expression of the same solution using generics.

Comment: The same can be done using `SectionModel sectionModel = 
 config.GetSection("SectionName").Get<SectionModel>();` [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern)

Comment: That's better than mine. Write an answer.